# How to have an instance of anonyme class from reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to have an instance of anonyme class from reflection?

I have this string :
 `"<object name='hello' id='654' />"`

with an **indetermined attribute parameters number**(and name)
from this I want to have an instance of anonyme class with a mapping between attribute and properties, and attributes values and properties values.

```
var anObject = new{name="hello",id=654};
```

I took the xml format for the string to ilustrate my words but I need a solution **from any string format**(I don't want to Xml Serialisation).

For Reed Copsey (please make abstraction of the context where I need it).
I plan to use this to inject DefaultRoute to the map route of an asp.net MVC 3 application

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "",
        "superweirdurlwithnostructure.whatever",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", id = 500 }
    );
```

referering to my question [File to define route in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135633/file-to-define-route-in-mvc3#comment17866274_13135633)

Comment: How do you plan to use this class instance?

Comment: How would the code know that `654` is an `int`, as opposed to a `string` that just happened to have a value that looked int-like? or a `float`? etc...?

Comment: You absolutely can't use dynamic objects here?

Comment: @nieve I didn't know dynamic object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make an anonymous class this way (at least not without major hoops using something like [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to actually write and compile code).

That being said, even if you *could* do this, there would be no good way to use this class.  Anonymous types are really intended for use within the function where they are defined, and they are turned into a full class which is generated by the compiler at *compile time*.

One option, potentially, would be to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic anObject = new ExpandoObject();
anObject.name = "hello";
anObject.id = 654;
```

You could also use this via `ExpandoObject`'s `IDictionary<string,object>` interface:

```
dynamic anObject = new ExpandoObject();
var setObject = (IDictionary<string,object>)anObject;
setObject["name"] = "hello";
setObject["id"] = 654;

// These can be accessed directly now
Console.WriteLine(anObject.name);
Console.WriteLine(anObject.id);
```

However, you're still going to need a good way to use this - without knowing how the code should access the variables, building types dynamically doesn't help solve many issues, and just creates more of them...

Comment: Since the parameters are indeterminate, it would probably be better to show the same, using the `IDictionary<string,object>` feature of `ExpandoObject`. But fundamentally: I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to use `Reflection.Emit` to create a new type with all the properties. Anonymous types are actually classes no different from any other with the exception that the compiler automatically creates their definition.

Depending on your scenario, `dynamic ExpandoObject` objects could be your answer.